# PHPMailer bounced mails not getting bounced right

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, email-bounces

I have written a PHP script, which sends mails. I'm sending them from "mail@something.com" and have also set the "Return-Path" to "bounce@something.com", but I'm still getting bounced mails to senders mail ("mail@something.com").

Here is stripped down code:

```
$this->mail = new PHPMailer();
$this->mail->isSMTP();
$this->mail->Host = 'host';
$this->mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$this->mail->Username = 'mail@something.com';
$this->mail->Password = 'pass';
$this->mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$this->mail->Port = 25;
$this->mail->ReturnPath = 'bounce@something.com';
$this->mail->From = 'mail@something.com';
$this->mail->send();
```

How could I force the bounced mails to go to the bounce mail account? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't use `ReturnPath` - set `Sender` instead. Support for the `ReturnPath` property was recently disabled in PHPMailer (in version 5.2.8) because it's invalid to set it at the point of sending. The return path is added by the receiver when it receives the message, and is set by putting your desired return path into the `Sender` property, which gets passed as the envelope sender during the SMTP conversation. `Sender` is set automatically when you call `setFrom`, but you can override it and just set it directly, like this:

```
$this->mail = new PHPMailer();
$this->mail->isSMTP();
$this->mail->Host = 'host';
$this->mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$this->mail->Username = 'mail@something.com';
$this->mail->Password = 'pass';
$this->mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$this->mail->Port = 25;
$this->mail->setFrom('mail@something.com');
$this->mail->Sender = 'bounce@something.com';
$this->mail->send();
```

Comment: this one worked for me, $mail->Sender = 'bounce@xxxxxxxx.nl'; So pitty your answer was not accepted...

Comment: I am using PHP_Mailer 5.2.10 and my php version is 5.4.9. "$this->mail->Sender" is not working for me. All the bounced emails are returning to the "$this->mail->AddReplyTo" address. Is this ($this->mail->AddReplyTo) causes any issue for the  "$this->mail->Sender" to function?

Comment: Why are you using old, buggy, insecure versions of both PHP and PHPMailer? Aside from that, there are plenty of mail servers that do things wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your code:

```
$this->mail->AddReplyTo("youraccount@gmail.com","Your name");
```